# Print jobs not being deleted from spooler

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, printing

On our LAN I have one particular machine that seems to be clogging up the spooler/queue every time it prints to one particular printer.

Server 2008 Print Server; Win7 Box.

Every other machine can print to this printer fine. This machine can print to other shared printers fine.

What happens when it prints is the job is spooled and sent to the printer. The job prints. The job does not get deleted from the spooler--it just sits there saying "Sent to printer".

The only way to get this printer back is to manually go into the Server 2008 box and run

```
net stop spooler
del C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS\*
net start spooler
```

The error...err, "event viewer" is helpful as always (read: not helpful at all).

I've tried rebooting the machine and re-installing the printer--neither fixed the issue.

Any ideas on where I can look? What might be wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it the machine or the user? Have you tried having the user login on another computer and print? Does it do it to a different user logged into that machine (a domain admin for example)? Do you have other win7 machines that print to that printer ok?

Comment: It is the machine. Domain admin can not print correctly from the machine either. Other users (on other machines) *can* print correctly to the printer. Thanks.

Comment: Re-image machine.  Beat user with LART for good measure.

Comment: @HopelessN00b or I could just change the port from WSD to TCP/IP and go out for a smoke. Yeah, think I'll do that :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverprint/thread/6e72268f-4ec2-43a2-9a29-750204b02c3f

Changing the port from WDS to TCP/IP fixes the issue.